# print a multiple divs and its data and save it in pdf

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to copy/save/print multiple divs with its content and save it in pdf file,Using jspdf am facing issues with alignments and copying images.

Can any suggestions to print div and save it in pdf file?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function PrintElem(elem)
    {
        Popup($(elem).html());
        //alert($(elem).html());
    }

    function Popup(data) 
    {
        var mywindow = window.open('', 'my div', 'height=400,width=600');
        mywindow.document.write('<html><head><title>my div</title>');
        /*optional stylesheet*/ //mywindow.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" type="text/css" />');
        mywindow.document.write('</head><body >');
        mywindow.document.write(data);
        mywindow.document.write('</body></html>');

        mywindow.document.close(); // necessary for IE >= 10
      //  mywindow.focus(); // necessary for IE >= 10

        mywindow.print();
        //mywindow.close();

        return true;
    }

</script>
```

Above code saving the details in xps extension,before that i want to catch the details into pdf file?it need to be like general pdf download

Please any suggestions,How to save printable data into pdf?

Comment: Please show us what you have tried. So we can make suggestions based on your findings.

Comment: <script>
function printTrigger(elementId) {
 alert("in print trigger");
    var getMyFrame = document.getElementById(elementId);
    getMyFrame.focus();
    getMyFrame.contentWindow.print();
}
</script>
<iframe id="iFramePdf" src="myPdfUrl.pdf" style="display:none;"></iframe>

Comment: Hi StijinvanGaal,Any possibility to print the element details into pdf file?

Answer (score 0):

Go and have a look at [jsPDF](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF). This will give you some support for creating a pdf.

You can create a pdf like so
HTML:

```
<div id="content">
     <h3>Hello, this is a H3 tag</h3>

    <p>a pararaph</p>
</div>
<div id="editor"></div>
<button id="cmd">generate PDF</button>
```

JavaScript:

```
var doc = new jsPDF();
var specialElementHandlers = {
    '#editor': function (element, renderer) {
        return true;
    }
};

$('#cmd').click(function () {
    doc.fromHTML($('#content').html(), 15, 15, {
        'width': 170,
            'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
    });
    doc.save('sample-file.pdf');
});
```

**EDIT**
also take a look at html2canvas, there is a tutorial [here](http://www.techumber.com/2015/04/html-to-pdf-conversion-using-javascript.html).
as far as i have read it, this should take some sort of a screenshot of the current DOM. Maybe this will help

Comment: I worked on jsPdf,As it not catching image url from amazon and even in page i have google charts displaying which are not coming using jsPdf,I dont have any option other than printing it,Even the print is not cathing the div scroll content....any other suggestions